# Non-Transparent Proxy Caching of SSL

Tags: web-services, rest, caching, ssl, proxy

I asked the question before but didn't phrase it quite right. I'm using RESTful principles to build a secure web-app that uses both transport authentication/encryption and message level security.

The message level security is essentially client-independent (still encrypted though), and hence this allows the individual messages to be cached, or stored on an intermediary server without significant risk of exposing private data.

Transport level security is needed to authenticate both end-points using TLS client-authentication. The situation is analogous to having a central mainframe where messages originate, and caches at each branch where the clients are located. I want the client->cache and cache->mainframe connections to be secured using TLS and the individual X509 Certificates. Hence, the client will know it is talking to a proxy, and the mainframe will know it is talking to the proxy and not directly to the client.

Is there some way of doing this using HTTP standards, and not through some hack?

Essentially, I want the client to try and access the mainframe URI, to know it has to go through the proxy, and use TLS with the proxy (with the proxy having its own certificate), and then for the proxy to proceed to connect to the mainframe (with each having their own certificate) on behalf of the client. The proxy can cache the data the mainframe returns, and use that instead of having to connect to the mainframe each time.

Does anybody know proxy/caching software or a method that will allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Would this get more responses on serverfault.com as it's essentially a server software/config question rather than a programming problem per se?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it sounds like you want a standard SSL reverse proxy with caching. You could do this without writing any code with Apache + mod_cache, configured as a reverse proxy.

The kicker is the message security. It'd only work if your requests are 100% cacheable based only on path/querystring, and if they were "unique by client" (eg, a client ID in the QS or something). Something tells me that one or both of these are not true. This would be pretty trivial to build in ASP.NET, or by extending mod_cache (basically just standard response caching, bucketed by the client cert thumbprint).